# How to reference the dependencies (jars) stored in hdfs on Hadoop?

Tags: java, hadoop, jar, dependencies, classpath

On Hadoop: I want to run a jar that has many dependencies (jars) stored into hdfs (I don't want to put them in the local file system).

How do I do that?

Answer (score -1):

You can put them on the class path of the client 
(Edge)node i.e the machine from where you are running the code (main jar)

Update: You can explore the -libjars option.

You can also check this very good blog.
http://grepalex.com/2013/02/25/hadoop-libjars/

Comment: Could you give an example. Also dependencies (jars) stored into hdfs I don't want to put them in the local file system on every node.

Comment: I suggest exploring the -libjars option once.

Comment: I think libjars for the local libraries not for ones in hdfs